# How to write htaccess for prerender with Angular and wordpress

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, angular-ui-router, prerender

I am using Angular in combination with wordpress. I am trying to make prerender work but I don't know how to implement it. Whenever I attach `?_escaped_fragment_=` to the end of the url it just shows the normal angular site and not the prerendered html.

I have added the fragment meta tag in the header and html5 to true in angular config.

.htaccess

```
# Change YOUR_TOKEN to your prerender token and uncomment that line if you want to cache urls and view crawl stats
# Change http://example.com (at the end of the last RewriteRule) to your website url

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    #RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MY TOKEN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://www.example.com$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also the apache mod_rewrite and mod_proxy modules are installed

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: Just copying from another thread: Can you make sure you have mod_rewrite.c and mod_proxy_http.c turned on? mod_proxy_http.c is required by prerender

Comment: Yes these modules are installed and loadModule lines are uncommented.

Comment: That looks to be correct. Don't forget to change http://www.example.com to your domain. If you remove all of the <IfModule ...> and </IfModule> do you get an error at all? If not, can you set a test header somewhere in there to see if it's being executed?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I got it working now. there was something wrong with apache not loading the proxy module correctly. I do have another problem now the root page is not rendering the dynamic content. here's the stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055024/prerender-with-anguar-ui-router-not-rendering-root-page-dynamic-content